# ¿API TIKTOK permite leer mis leads de mis formularios ads?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

Tiktok permite poder con la API leer y mostrar mis lead captados en formularios de campaña en JAVASCRIPT?. pues no veo documentación ni videos referente a este tema, solo de como se puede ver videos, like, etc. Esta habilitado para Latinoamérica?.

Solo he encontrado endpoints de la V2 pero ya esta en la V3 y solo veo lista de audiencia, pero no lista de lead captados por formularios tiktok.

Existirá algo asi?

```
const response = await fetch('https://open.tiktokapis.com/leads', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
```